# What does withReplacement do, if specified for sample against a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

Reading the spark documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample

There is this boolean parameter `withReplacement` without much explanation.

> sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)

What is it and how do we use it?

Comment: with replacement means a row of data can be selected multiple times into the sample and no replacement means a row can only be selected only once into the sample

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The parameter `withReplacement` controls the Uniqueness of `sample` result. If we treat a Dataset as a bucket of balls, `withReplacement=true` means, taking a random ball out of the bucket and place it back into it. that means, the same ball can be picked up again.

Assuming all unique elements in a Dataset:

- `withReplacement=true`, same element can be produced more than once as the result of `sample`.
- `withReplacement=false`, each element of the dataset will be sampled only once.

  ```
     import spark.implicits._

      val df = Seq(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).toDF("ids")

      df.show()

      df.sample(true, 0.5, 5)
        .show

      df.sample(false, 0.5, 5)
        .show
  ```

  Result

  ```
  +---+
  |ids|
  +---+
  |  1|
  |  2|
  |  3|
  |  5|
  |  6|
  |  7|
  |  8|
  |  9|
  | 10|
  +---+

  +---+
  |ids|
  +---+
  |  6|
  |  7|
  |  7|
  |  9|
  | 10|
  +---+

  +---+
  |ids|
  +---+
  |  1|
  |  3|
  |  7|
  |  8|
  |  9|
  +---+
  ```

Answer (score -3):

This is actually mentioned in the spark docs version 2.3.
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample

withReplacement – Sample with replacement

```
case class Member(id: Int, name: String, role: String)

val member1 = new Member(1, "User1", "Data Engineer")
val member2 = new Member(2, "User2", "Software Engineer")
val member3 = new Member(3, "User3", "DevOps Engineer")

val memberDF = Seq(member1, member2, member3).toDF
memberDF.sample(true, 0.4).show

+---+-----+-----------------+
| id| name|             role|
+---+-----+-----------------+
|  1|User1|    Data Engineer|
|  2|User2|Software Engineer|
+---+-----+-----------------+

memberDF.sample(true, 0.4).show

+---+-----+---------------+
| id| name|           role|
+---+-----+---------------+
|  3|User3|DevOps Engineer|
+---+-----+---------------+

memberDF.sample(true, 0.4).show

+---+-----+-----------------+
| id| name|             role|
+---+-----+-----------------+
|  2|User2|Software Engineer|
|  3|User3|  DevOps Engineer|
+---+-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Could you explain with an example of what the difference is? What is with replacement and what is without replacement?

Comment: Updated my answer. @YuchenZhong

Comment: Thanks, but do these examples tell us anything? Why the 1st and 3rd examples have two rows, but the 2nd one only have only one rows?